# I can not use EL <c:out value="${inquiryListID.id}"/> in my jsp,

Tags: jsp, el, struts1

I use "Working with server: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
       Servlet Specification: 2.5 
       JSP version: 2.1"
In my JSP page, I used EL with this tag `<c:out value="${inquiryListID.id}"/>` .

When it renders the page, it is displaying ${inquiryListID.id} only.

Its value does not show.

Please explain me what to do?

Answer (score 2):

In the page directive of your jsp place this attribute isELIgnored="false"

Example :  <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>

This should display the value of ${inquiryListID.id}

check if this works